# Geolocation service for mobile device

Tags: web-services, http, mobile, geolocation, gps

Is there any reliable geolocation service which could provide me with the latitude and longitude of a mobile device.
I need something like Google Gears(which is unfortunately discontinued) where I can give various data about the carriers cell the device is currently in etc. and get the latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that for a GSM Blackberry device with OS 5 there is no good alternative for getting the location to the standard satellite lock.

WIFI and Cellsite services are not available and unless you have a very good server with huge database with locations of carrier cells all over the world you cannot do anything effective.

Answer (score 2):

If the device you have does not support the Location API in HTML5, then you can use the IP address to get the location of the device. Have a look at services like [www.maxmind.com](http://www.maxmind.com). They have a basic free service that does location lookup basedon IP. The free service is accurate to city level. Beware that:

- You'll need to implement this server side
- It's accuracy is limited, and can be confused by people connecting over corporate networks, or proxies like Opera Mobile Browser.

Comment: thanks this seems interesting but my requirements are for higher precision - maybe 1km. City level is just not accurate enough.

Comment: What is your environment? If you're building a web application, your only hope for anything more precise than IP geolocation would be the HTML5 geolocation api.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 includes a geolocation method: see http://html5demos.com/geo

Comment: The device I use does not support html 5. I suppose that the html5 demo uses some google service like google maps or something to make the geolocation - do you know if it is documented somewhere?

Comment: it is infact html5 that gets the location...                       if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
  error('not supported');
}                                                                          are you sure your device doesn't support it, cause i have an incredible and its supported.

Comment: My device is blackberry with OS5. In OS6 it is supported though.

Comment: does your device not have gps?

Comment: Yes it does. But gps doesn't work well in indoors and requires more time to get first satelite fix. My question is about geolocation i.e. I do not need to use GPS - I want to be able to get the coordinates from the nearby carrier cells.

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Location-APIs-Start-to-finish/ta-p/571949, you said it was os 5

Comment: yes but this does not work in os5 gsm devices. When you create a LocationProvider with a criteria for cellsite geologation that provider is null which by spec means that it could not be created and is not supported for the given criteria. That code compiles even for older os 4.6 but does not actually work and is not supported. For os6 works well though. I have also seen reports of it working on  some os 5 devices but CDMA devices not GSM.